# Why do we need to install pytz package when we want to use Django with MongoDB?

Tags: django, mongodb

After many research, i found that to use Django with MongoDB, we have to install pytz and downgrade pymongo to 3.12.3, because the new version of pymongo (4.0 from 29.11.2021) is not supported by Djongo 1.3.6.
But what's the interest of pytz ?

When i try to use Django with MongoDB without installing pytz, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `pytz` is no longer a requirement for Django (or the Python ecosystem at large due to [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/zoneinfo.html#module-zoneinfo) starting from Python 3.9), but the requirements for Djongo haven't been updated [and it does hard-require `pytz`](https://github.com/doableware/djongo/blob/e7170bb365a5f8e3c3791a8428124fac1c88ce99/djongo/operations.py#L1).